# java.lang.classCastException : arraylist incompatible/ not using arraylist

Tags: hibernate, arraylist, classcastexception

Using Hibernate and GenericDAO interface, I'm gestting this error :
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with OperationalPostBO

The problem is in this line of code : 
OperationalPostBO operationalPostBO = operationalPostDAO.findOperationalPostByOpCode(opCode);

The problem is : I'm not using any arrayList in all of my code. I'm only using java.util.Set, and implementing it by Hashset.

hbm file :
`

```
    <property name="opCode" column="OPCODE" type="string" />
    <property name="label" column="LABEL" type="string" />
    <property name="type" column="TYPE" type="string" />

    <set name="portfolioList" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="OPERATIONALPOST_OID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="PortfolioBO" />
    </set>

    <many-to-one name="structureElement" class="StructureElementBO" column="STRUCTUREELEMENT_OID" />

</class>
<query name="OperationalPostBO.findOperationalPostByOpCode">
    <![CDATA[select o from OperationalPostBO o where o.opCode = ?]]>
</query>
```

`

Comment: "I'm not using any arrayList in all of my code" - I suspect this is false

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NimChimpsky. I did a search on the whole project and i did not find any "arraylist". Even in the "operationalPost.hbm.xml" I'm using <set></set>. Also, the "find" method is not even supposed to return a list, it is supposed to return one item

Comment: show the code of findOperationalPostByOpCode()

Comment: it is implemented in an hbm file :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<query name="OperationalPostBO.findOperationalPostByOpCode">
    <![CDATA[select o from OperationalPostBO o where o.opCode = ?]]>
</query>
```

Returns a list.

PortfolioList (which is actually a set) is something else.

So something like:

```
Collection<OperationalPostBO> operationalPostBOs = operationalPostDAO.findOperationalPostByOpCode(opCode);
```

Comment: Yes you're right. But it is a nested list in the "OperationalPostBO". What's the solution?

Comment: create a reference that is a List not a Set, or a Collection even. See edit